# Create schedule save data in android service based on system time

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want create app android run something in service and repeat after 1 hours but it based on the system clock, 01:00,02:00,.... So, What I have to do? AlarmManager? please help me. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `AlarmManager` is a decent option.  You may also look at `JobScheduler` as another option.  For more details on the ins and outs of using `AlarmManager`, see [this article](http://po.st/7UpipA).

Comment: but if I install app at 3:10, I want setup alarm begin 4:00 and repeat at 5:00,6:00,... How does AlarmManager work? @Larry

Comment: Your app will still need to be run by the user and it will have to set the alarm. See the article, it explains how it use it and pitfalls to watch for, particularly with regards to power.